# Set Calendar to Hour of day

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am new to java and android and I am trying to develop an alarm clock app.

I have tried to set the calendar hour to `HOUR_OF_DAY` but it shows the error

```
Non static method 'set(int, int)' cannot be referenced from a static context.
```

I got the error on this line of code:

```
Calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarm_timepicker.getHour());
```

Comment: show us your code

Answer (score 0):

By your code, I see that you are not creating a calender object and trying to call Calender class method which is non-static (hence requires an object to call).

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); //Cal is now an object
 cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarm_timepicker.getHour()); // Call set method using object.
```